# What is the halachic source for objection to sex before marriage?

Tags: marriage, sexuality

As far as im aware the prohibition of Shomer Negiah comes from two pesukim in ויקרא:

> אִישׁ אִישׁ אֶל-כָּל-שְׁאֵר בְּשָׂרוֹ, לֹא תִקְרְבוּ לְגַלּוֹת עֶרְוָה:  אֲנִי יְהוָה
>   "None of you shall come near anyone of his own flesh to uncover
>   nakedness: I am the Lord". (18:6)

and

> וְאֶל-אִשָּׁה בְּנִדַּת טֻמְאָתָהּ--לֹא תִקְרַב לְגַלּוֹת עֶרְוָתָהּ
>   "Do not come near a woman during her period of uncleanness (niddah) to
>   uncover her nakedness". (18:19)

The second verse, which prohibits sex with a niddah (menstruating woman) applies not only to one's wife, but to all women, married or otherwise, because unmarried women are considered to be in a constant state of niddah because they do not go to mikvah (ritual immersion). The rabbis extended this prohibition beyond sex to include any type of touching, whether a handshake or a hug.

Is it possible to have sex with an unmarried woman if she went to mikvah?

Comment: Ah thanks. That didn't come up in my search